# Browser-independent way to save text in a TextAreaFor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, text, cross-browser, textarea

Using ASP.NET MVC, I have a View that contains a TextAreaFor, where I want users to be able to type in some notes and save them on-the-fly, see notes that were saved there before (whether by them or some other user), as well as modify existing notes (like to add additional notes).  Here's what I have....

The divs in the View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InternalNotes" class="control-label">Internal Notes</label>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(w => w.InternalNotes, new { @class = "form-control" , @id="notes" })  @*this is editable*@
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <button type="button" id="savenotes" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save Request Notes</button>
            <div style="color:green; display:none" id="notessuccess">Notes successfully saved</div>
            <div style="color:red; display:none" id="noteserror">Notes unable to be saved</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <button type="submit" id="deletereq" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" value="delete" name="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete Request</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the user could type something into the TextAreaFor, then hit the "savenotes" button, which should save them via Ajax.  This is the jQuery for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#savenotes").click(function () {

        $("#notessuccess").hide();
        $("#noteserror").hide();

        var id = @Model.AccessRequestId;
        var notes = document.getElementById("notes").textContent;  //innerText;

        $.ajax({
            data: { 'id': id, 'notes': notes },
            type: 'POST',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/Administration/SaveRequestNotes',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success == "ok") {
                    $("#notessuccess").fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $("#noteserror").fadeIn();
                }
            },
            fail: function (data) {
                $("#noteserror").fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The "innerText" is commented out because that's what I was originally using, but it was only working in Internet Explorer - another user is using Chrome, where he could see the other user's notes that were already there, but when he'd try to save notes in addition to theirs, it would blow it all out so the notes would be empty!

So I changed it to "textContent".  That still works in Internet Explorer, but now in both Chrome and Firefox while it won't empty out existing notes, it still won't save new notes added.  What is a browser-independent way I can make this work so everyone's notes will get properly saved whatever they are using?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `val()` method get the text user entered to the textarea

```
var notes = $("#notes").val();
alert(notes);
```

You might also consider using the Url.Action helper method to generate the correct relative path to your action method.

```
 url: '@Url.Action("SaveRequestNotes","Administration")',
```

Comment: Looks like using .val() worked.  Ugh, I don't know why I didn't think to use that before....I figured it would be something stupid like that!  Just wondering how is using @Url.Action better than using what I have now?

Comment: It creates the correct relative path irrespective of your url.